# Storing compressed data in a cookie

Tags: http, encryption, cookies, compression, session-cookies

What's the best way to store compressed data in a cookie?  The reasons I want to do this are:

1. I want to store as much data as possible in 1 cookie
2. I want performance to be as fast as possible in terms of data transfer
3. I don't want it to be so obvious what I'm storing exactly to prevent easy tampering
4. There are many values, hopefully the best mechanism to do this allows for easy retrieval

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in php, but you should easily find base64 and gzip functions in java:

1. Serialize your object
2. Append a hash to prevent tampering (e.g. md5sum(serialized + secret))
3. Compress the string with gzip
4. Encode the result with base64

To get the original data, just apply the reverse functions in the reverse order. You said only one cookie, but it is possible to split the content in 2 or more cookies with the maximum size of 4k as a 5th step (and join them later). When comparing the size of the result, don't forget to take into account that the serialized string may have chars such as '{' and ':' that are urlencoded to '%7B' and '%3A', making the string longer.

Some links that may be useful:

- [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/): a fast serialization framework for java
- [Cookies Manager+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/): firefox extension to view/edit cookies

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what server-side technologies you are using, but [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/064b41e4-60bc-4d35-9136-368603bcc27a/7zip-lzma-inmemory-com.aspx) is a method which compresses cookies in ASP.NET using C# and the [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) library.

Comment: I'm using Java/Spring on the server, but I guess I was looking for a more general solution...  If there's a good library that also handles that solution for me, all the better.